# Python Dictionary - Invalid Syntax

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

Why does the following code throw an invalid syntax error?

```
grads = {"dW1": dW1, 
         "db1": db1, 
         "dW2": dW2, 
         "db2": db2}
```

It gives the following error

```
File "<ipython-input-27-f129b09e7ac8>", line 40
    grads = {"dW1": dW1,
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: will you please provide the full code, the line you have provided doesn't seem to have any error i think the line just above the dictionary has some error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the scope you are sharing. You have a syntax error above / before declaring `grads`

Comment: Thanks, there was a parenthesis error in the line before.